# Using a custom DLL in Silverlight

Tags: vb.net, silverlight, silverlight-5.0

I'm testing and trying to understand how to create a DLL and call a function from it in my Silverlight project. I'm getting an exception: Unable to find an entry point named 'WriteTextFile' in DLL 'C:\temp\TestDLL.dll'. So I'm doing something wrong.

Here is my code for the very simple DLL:

```
Imports System.IO

Public Class Class1

    Private Shared dir As String = "C:\TEMP"
    Private Shared file As String = "TestDLL.txt"

    Public Shared Sub WriteTextFile()
        Using wr As New StreamWriter(System.IO.Path.Combine(dir, file))
            wr.WriteLine("Call to function WriteTextFile()")
        End Using
    End Sub

End Class
```

And this is what I'm doing in my Silverlight:

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices


Partial Public Class MainPage
    Inherits UserControl

    <DllImport("C:\temp\TestDLL.dll")> _
    <AllowReversePInvokeCalls()> _
    Friend Shared Sub WriteTextFile()
    End Sub

    Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        WriteTextFile()
    End Sub

End Class
```

I need some pointing to the right direction here :)

The AllowReversePInvokeCalls part is just something I tried out after doing some reading around the web but it didn't change anything. Also I've tried to set the EntryPoint in the DLLImport but that doesn't do anything either.

Edit:

I tried this DLL and pinvoke in regular WPF application and I get the same error so this is not related to Silverligth. Maybe in my DLL then?

Comment: Note - Silverlight uses a different version of the .NET runtime to regular .NET applications. So if you've built `TestDLL.dll` using the regular .NET runtime, a Silverlight application won't be able to run it.

Comment: @ChrisF are you sure of that? The OP is using P/Invoke, not linking into his SL project.

Comment: @jv42 - I *think* so - but I'm not 100% sure, hence the comment rather than an answer.

Comment: In SL5 I should be able to use it like above. When directly adding the DLL as a reference it fails because it's built in full .NET. Examples what I've found usually import a function from user32.dll etc. system DLL file but I would like to import functions from a custom made DLL so I can use functions that need full framework in a silverlight app running OOB with elevated rights.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so it looks like this can't be done simply because using pinvoke requires a standard dll and I can't do those with VB .NET. So I'll need to try something else :)

If anyone has more information about this and like to share it I would appreciate that. Or correct me if I've understood the issue wrong.